# Optimising MySQL count() with INNER JOIN (550k rows)

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, mysql-5.7

I have the query below, which is currently taking approx 1 - 1.5 seconds to run in a MySQL 5.7 database. It's being called from a web application, and whilst I'll be implementing caching at the application (PHP) level, I'd still like to try and speed up this query if possible. There are approx 550k rows in the table.

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS aggregate
FROM
    `establishments`
    INNER JOIN `inspections` ON `inspections`.`id` = `establishments`.`latest_inspection_id`
    INNER JOIN `ratings` ON `ratings`.`id` = `inspections`.`rating_id`
WHERE
    `establishments`.`latest_inspection_id` IS NOT NULL
    AND `ratings`.`key` in('best', 'average', 'poor', 'terrible', 'exempt')
    AND `establishments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

This is the result of EXPLAIN on the query:

```
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type   | possible_keys                               | key     | key_len | ref                                               | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
|----|-------------|----------------|------------|--------|---------------------------------------------|---------|---------|---------------------------------------------------|--------|----------|-------------|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | establishments |            | ALL    | establishments_latest_inspection_id_foreign |         |         |                                                   | 526482 |     5.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inspections    |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,inspections_rating_id_foreign       | PRIMARY | 8       | fhrs_insights.establishments.latest_inspection_id |      1 |   100.00 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ratings        |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ratings_key_unique                  | PRIMARY | 8       | fhrs_insights.inspections.rating_id               |      1 |    33.33 | Using where |
```

Any advice on how I can speed this up?

Comment: What business logic depends on knowing the _exact number_ of establishments, inspected or not?

Comment: Add DDL for all tables.

Comment: Is the `COUNT(*)` the number of ratings?  What kind of "establishments"?  You seem to have 500K of them.

Answer (score 0):

First I would try index on establishments (latest_inspection_id, deleted_at).
Also it may has a sense to eliminate join with ratings table using condition directly on `inspections`.`rating_id` instead. I mean AND `inspections`.`rating_id` IN (..list of corresponding ids..)

Comment: Flip that index.  It would be better to have the "equal-like" test first (`IS NULL`).

Comment: @RickJames I wasn't sure that MySQL will make a proper estimation for NULL value. In theory you are right and it has a sense to test (deleted_at, latest_inspection_id). But a couple of times I faced with inefficient execution plans in old versions of MySQL when server needed to estimate the number of rows where column is null and it chose not to use index. If the table contains a small number of deleted records, the order of the columns in the index should not greatly affect the performance of this query.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

1. Create indexes for the required columns:

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX idx_latest_inspection_id ON establishments (latest_inspection_id);`
   CREATE INDEX idx_ratings_key ON ratings (key);
   CREATE INDEX idx_deleted_at ON establishments (deleted_at);
   ```
2. Use the EXIST clause:

   ```sql
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate
   FROM establishments e
   WHERE
       e.latest_inspection_id IS NOT NULL
       AND e.deleted_at IS NULL
       AND EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM inspections i
           INNER JOIN ratings r ON i.rating_id = r.id
           WHERE i.id = e.latest_inspection_id AND r.key IN ('best', 'average', 'poor', 'terrible', 'exempt')
       )
   ```